# Multiple sudo -S in one command problem

Tags: command-line, password, heroku

I wonder how can I perform that command without inputing manually the password:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sudo -S sh
```

Currently it still asks me for password, how to solve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Piping from some web page to a shell (especially a root shell) makes me very nervous. Why not save the downloaded script, maybe validate it a bit, then use `echo "password" | sudo -S bash /path/to/script`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson while I agree with you, at this level how could someone validate the script?

Comment: @roaima For heroku specifically, I'd use a different install method if one is available (as a snap, with `yay` or `npm install` or...). It's very difficult in general (see the links [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213401) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213116) for discussion). At the very least, I'd use `curl -f` (i.e. fail if error), test the exit status of `curl`, and then run `file` on the download to make sure it's actually a shell script (not something like an HTML error page).

Comment: But I am a very newbie in Linux. I would very much prefer the simple method similar to mine one.

Comment: A simple method can easily create a bigger hole for you to dig your way out of. [Excuse the dangling preposition.]  The script calls another curl/wget and untars that on the fly -- no checksum validation for example. Minimum requirement is a complete backup for safety.

Comment: You _should_ be entering a password. It gives you time to think over what you're about to do _as root_ to your system

Answer (score -2):

I cannot enter the password manually because this image with Linux and Heroku runs on Docker container. Thanks for any answer but I needed to find a solution on my own. Here is my changed code:

```
RUN echo "password" | sudo -S curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh -o ~/heroku.sh
RUN echo "password" | sudo -S sh ~/heroku.sh`
```

It seems that it works...

Comment: "Was it that hard?" – I think users here are not eager to assist you in shooting next to your foot. The comments you got were kinda like "move that gun away". :D

Comment: You don't (or shouldn't) need the first `sudo`

Comment: The snark isn't appreciated.  If people haven't given you the answer you wanted, that is because they didn't know it and not out of spite.  And note that this is not what you asked for: you are now running two separate, independent commands but your question was about doing it in a single step.